# Adwords and Form Tracking

Tags: forms, tracking, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

Im not an expert in Google Tracking and Adwords and i had a request where a client wants to track the people who submit a contact form on a website, coming from an adwords ad.

So someone lands on a specific site on the clients site via Adwords, then fills out the contact form on that site. Now they want to know how many people coming from adwords ads, are willing to submit the form.

This seems to be very obvious, and i thought there might be already a solution for this.

Conversion Tracking already happens when the form is submitted, but they cannot comprehend whether someone submitted the form coming from adwords or or not.

I´ve been told to save the GET-Parameter from the Adwords-Link inside the database, the website is running on, every time the form is submitted. That doesnt seem to be the right way. Also there are some security issues with that.

Can anyone give some advice, how this could be achieved.

I hope i explained that right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to save source into DB**:
Simpliest way migth be *parsing UTM parameters and populate the hidden fields in the form*, so you know that user came from AdWords or any other source.

If you are using automatic tagging (which I would recommend), you are going after GLCID parameter, if manual, it's just utm_source.

I would do tracking from all sources (not only AdWords) - it might happen that you also need to know if user came through Facebook, LinkedIn article or so.

More on tracking sources into database [here](http://www.terminusapp.com/blog/add-utm-referrer-lead-forms/) and [here](https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2012/09/06/how-to-save-google-analytics-referrer-data-to-database/). More on AdWords tagging [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en).

**If you only need to know if people from AdWords submit forms** (=converts):
Chances are, that you already know. See Google Analytics. Filter out segment of people who did goal of sumbmiting form and see Aquisition -> All traffic.

More on Google Analytics [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You should check and make sure you have auto-tagging enabled. The best way to do this in Google Analytics go into the Admin > Property column > Product Linking section > Adwords Linking.

Once you have Adwords and Analytics linked up simply go back to the Reporting tab and navigate to Acquisition > Adwords > Campaigns as shown [here](http://screencast.com/t/FE8FamIT3)

If you have properly set up your goals in Analytics you can use the Conversion filter to select the goal you want to view and this will show you all goal conversions that came from Adwords.